# Building relative to src/ directory with SCons

Tags: scons

I have an app with the following (I would have thought quite common) directory hierarchy:

```
/src
    subdir1/  # Subdirs with more source files.
        more.c
        SConscript
    foo.c     # Source files.
    foo.h
    SConscript
/other        # Other top-level directories with no source code.
/stuff        # However, there are other assets I may want to build.
README        # Other top-level files.
SConstruct
```

The problem is that when I run `scons` from the top-level directory, it calls `gcc` from that directory without `cd`ing into `src`, like this:

```
gcc -o src/foo.o src/foo.c
```

This is problematic for several reasons:

1. Within my program, I `#include` files giving the path relative to the `src` directory. For example, `more.c` could include `foo.h` with `#include "foo.h"`. This fails because GCC is run from the parent directory. I don't want to change my includes to `#include "src/foo.h"`.
2. I use the `__FILE__` special macro for things like logging. When built from the top-level directory, GCC puts "`src/`" at the front of all filenames, since that was the path it was given to compile. This may seem picky, but I don't want that, because I think of my source tree as being relative to the `src` directory.

(**Edit**: I should add that obviously #1 can be fixed by adding `-Isrc` as a flag to GCC, but this seems like more hacks around the main issue.)

How can I make SCons `cd` into the `src` directory before calling `gcc`?

- I don't want to get rid of the `src` directory and move everything up, because there are lots of other (non-code) files at the top level.
- I don't want SCons to `cd` into every subdirectory. It should just `cd` into `src` and then build all files in the hierarchy from there.
- I could solve this by moving `SConscript` inside the `src` directory and running it from there, perhaps using a `Makefile` at the top level. But this seems quite hacky, and I also do want to use SCons to build (non-code) assets in other directories than `src`.

I've read that you can make a custom `Builder` and make it change directories. However, I do not want to write a whole new `Builder` for C/C++. Is there a way to modify the behaviour of an existing builder without writing one from scratch? Also, on one forum, someone said that changing directories from within a `Builder` would break parallel builds since it would change the directory that other tasks are building from. Is this true?

Comment: This seems like what I'd want for my problem as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519577/scons-link-program-without-build-directory-in-link-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is just how SCons works, and its not possible to avoid/change. I've been looking for some supporting documentation in its favor, and havent found any. Its just something Ive become used to.

As you mention, the include paths are simple to fix. The harder part is the `__FILE__` macro. I hadnt ever noticed this until you mentioned it. Unfortunately, I think the only way around this is to strip the path in the logger, which is a rather ugly fix.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. Well, I have updated my logger so that it strips out the entire path, and just shows the filename (this is probably better anyway, since the logs look much cleaner and you can usually guess the path if you need to). I guess I can live with this now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `src` to your `env['CPPPATH']` which will fix the include paths.

```py
env.Append(CPPPATH=[Dir('src')])
```

However, this doesn't solve the problem with `__FILE__`.